# Facebook messenger plugin not working properly in the mobile site

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I have used facebook messenger plugin on my site. It is working fine on the desktop version but on the mobile version it is causing issues. I am unable to click on any of the links on the site in mobile version.
For the first time the chat box opens but later not even the chatbox opens

the javascript and HTML code I have used

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId : '371291917550',
autoLogAppEvents : true,
xfbml : true,
version : 'v2.11'
});
};
(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I put this just below the opening of body tag

html code

```
<div class="fb-customerchat"
page_id="641020449311185"
ref="OPTIONAL_WEBHOOK_PARAM">
</div>
```

I put the html code just below the  tag.

Things i have done

1. I have whitelisted the domain with fb
   and the code is working properly on desktop but not on the mobile

Comment: Which mobile browsers? The feature is in beta so maybe its just not support on mobile

Comment: @AshleyMedway  google chrome

Comment: @AshleyMedway it supports mobile sites also as mentioned on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin#browser_support

Comment: Can you connect it up to a PC and inspect console errors?

Comment: @AshleyMedway There is no error related to messenger code